# A/B Testing Across Multiple Ads

Tags: r

I'm working with the following data:

```
Impressions<-c(6133,5400,4066,3546)
Conversions<-c(18,14,10,3)
Ratio<-Conversions/Impressions
dat<-data.frame(Impressions,Conversions,Ratio)
```

Is there a way to build out an A/B Test for A/B, A/C, A/D, B/A, B/C, B/D...? This way having a significance test for each ad against each other?

Comment: Yes. What have you already tried?

Comment: I'm still learning; haven't tried anything yet, lost on the process.

Comment: Start with how you would do one comparison. When you've solved that, move on to how to do multiple tests.

Comment: I approached this by `Z=1.96
M<-mean(dat$ConversionRate)
SEMean<-sd(dat$ConversionRate)/sqrt(length(dat$ConversionRate))
dat$UpperLim<-M+(1.96*SEMean)
dat$LowerLim<-M-(1.96*SEMean)
dat$StatSig<-ifelse(dat$ConversionRate>dat$UpperLim|dat$ConversionRate<dat$LowerLim,"Significant","Insignificant")`  @Heroka Is there an easier way?

Comment: What statistical test are you using? In your example, what are you comparing with what?

Comment: I treated this as a one-sample t-test where each ad was compared against the mean.